# Slide a UITableView down when searchbar and scope bar options appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I am using ios 9 and have implemented a searchController with a search bar that when tapped, opens and shows 3 scope options. The UITableView is below it.

What function do I need to overwrite/extend to make the UITableView slide down under the new scope bar? The scope bar covers some of my UITableViewCells. When the search is done, I also need to make the table view slide back up. How is this done?

Comment: Change frame of TableView with an animation? (Sorry, I know its crude but reckon that will get the job done)

Comment: What function calls the scope bar to appear where I can change the frame or contentOffset?

Comment: When searchbar is tapped i.e. it becomes first Responder. That's when you want the tableView to slide down right?

Comment: how do i grab the first responder?

Comment: Use delegate methods of UISearchbar. e.g. `searchBarShouldBeginEditing`. for more information read https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing:

Comment: still not working smoothly either with ios 9